# MS ACCESS, VBA SQL Insert command semicolon issue

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to sort out some VBA in Access today with very limited knowledge. I have constructed the code below for a simple insert into a table within the same access database.

I am getting the error 
"Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement."

However I have the semicolon in there. I can only assume I have made a rookie error with syntax somewhere but after spending far too long trying I am stumped, any pointers much appreciated!

```
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim InDate As Date
Dim VacNum As String
Dim Stage As String

InDate = Now()
VacNum = Me.Vacancy_No
Stage = Me.Current_Stage

StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Stage (Vacancy_ID,StageDate,Stage) VALUES ('" & VacNum & "','" & InDate & "','" & Stage & "' );"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is at risk for SQL injection, and that's probably why you're getting this message.

The likely cause of this error is that one of your field contains a single quote, making the SQL malfunction.

The proper solution to this is to parameterize:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", "INSERT INTO Stage (Vacancy_ID,StageDate,Stage) VALUES (@Value1,@Value2,@Value3 );")
qdf.Parameters("@Value1") = VacNum 
qdf.Parameters("@Value2") = InDate 
qdf.Parameters("@Value3") = Stage 
qdf.Execute
```

Comment: Thankyou, that worked well,

I will find some time later today to look into and understand how its working, i would always rather do things the proper way, now i know what to look up.

Many thanks

Comment: You can review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/7296893), it might provide you more insight. Also, one of the many sources on SQL injection might provide some insight.